# Google alert policy triggers issues based on cloud storage bucket object count

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have been trying to setup alert policies(thru stack-driver) to get email notifications whenever there is new object in the cloud storage bucket.

But the issue here is, it works sometimes after a while and most of the other times, it wont.

How do we make the alerts triggered immediately as in when there is a new file in the bucket(multiple times per day).

Below is the code:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
  display_name = "File notification"
  combiner     = "OR"
  notification_channels = ["${google_monitoring_notification_channel.email.name}"]

  conditions {
    display_name = "File Notification"

    condition_threshold {
      comparison        = "COMPARISON_LT"
      duration          = "60s" 
      filter            = "metric.type=\"storage.googleapis.com/storage/object_count\" resource.type=\"gcs_bucket\" resource.label.\"bucket_name\"=\"realbucketname\""
      threshold_value   = 1

      aggregations {
        alignment_period        = "60s"
        per_series_aligner      = "ALIGN_COUNT"
      }

      trigger {
        count = 1
      }
    }
  }
  documentation {
    content = "There is a new file"
  }
}
```

Appreciate your inputs!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you. I had it fixed by removing aggregations in my scripts,

It worked as expected now !!!

```
    condition_threshold {   
      comparison        = "COMPARISON_GT"
      duration          = "60s" 
      filter            = "metric.type=\"storage.googleapis.com/storage/object_count\" resource.type=\"gcs_bucket\" resource.label.\"bucket_name\"=\"realbucketname\""
      threshold_value   = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The object count metric is measured once per day, so it is possible that the condition will only trigger once per day. This is most likely why your alerts are not consistent.

If possible the recommend solution to view changes to objects in your bucket is through [pub/sub notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes). 
Using pub/sub notifications you can get notified when many different [events](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#events) occur inside your bucket.

Here is an example of the gsutil command you would use to be notified when an object is created in your bucket. The -e specifies that I only want the notification to occur when a specific event takes place, in this case it is when a file is uploaded to the bucket.

```
gsutil notification create -t [TOPIC_NAME] -f json gs://[BUCKET_NAME] -e OBJECT_FINALIZE
```

You would then create a [subscriber](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#manage_subs) to receive the notification.

Here is a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/use-cloud-pubsub-cloud-storage-app-engine) on managing notifications on buckets via App Engine.

You can also look into using [cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) that make use of stand-alone functions in response to events (adding files to bucket). To send emails via functions you can make use of third party services such as [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configure-third-party-notifications#email_notifications). You can also follow this [third-party tutorial](https://dev.to/i_maka/google-cloud-functions-sending-emails-using-gmail-smtp-and-nodemailer-1lij) on using SMTP and nodemailer to send emails.